# Develop an UI application that interacts with a C + + Library

Tags: c++, user-interface, java-native-interface, wxwidgets

I do not have a technical question about a problem. I am writing to get a hint about a possible technology to use.

I have a library developed in `C++` and I have to write an application with UI (multi-platform) that uses this library.
I have little time to write this application so I'm looking for something really simple and fast to use.

my first idea is to write your application in Java UI + and use `JNI` to interface with the `C++` Library. I think it is quite simple and fast to develop the UI with java .. but several problems may arise using JNI.

A second idea is to use something like `wxWidgets` to write everything in C++ and not have to have problems to use something different from `C++` (`JNI`)

In your opinion, what is the best solution?
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Any C++ UI system would work very well with a C++ library. QT is the biggest, but wxWidgets should work well.

Comment: You did not tell us what is your library doing. It could help us to know a bit ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider coding the GUI part with [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/)

<sup>My *opinion* is that Qt is better than WxWidget for such developments</sup>

Qt is a free C++ multi-platform software library for GUIs. Qt runs on many systems and is very well documented.

Coding with Qt is certainly less painful than using JNI...

Comment: What are the differences between Qt-project and http://qt.digia.com/?
Is Qt-project the qt free version?